# User optional Attribute Route to indicate tenant in dotnet core web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, .net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

Is there a way to define optional route parameter for a REST dotnet core webapi project?

I'd like to define an optional `tenant` parameter within my API controller. If the parameter is present, I'd like to use it to filter my queries.

`api.example.com/tenant1/users` -> all users of tenant1

`api.example.com/users` -> all users in the system

```
 [Route ("{tenant:guid?}/[controller]")]
    public class UsersController {

        // GET api.example.com/{tenant}/users
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers (Guid tenant) {
            ...
            if(tentant != null){
              var users = await _db.Users.GetAllByTentant(tenant);
              return Ok (users);
            } else {
              var users = await _db.Users.GetAll();
              return Ok (users);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I'd use query string params:

Filter by tenant:
 // GET api.example.com/users?tenantId={guid}

No Filter:
// GET api.example.com/users

Comment: I'd like to keep the optional tenant logic within my url paths

Comment: Then just add another endpoint // GET api.example.com/users. From the client perspective, this will behave as if tenant is optional.

Comment: Not sure how to get the tenant into the url before the [controller]

Comment: Specify your route on your actions instead of the controller. Add a new action GetUsers() with the // GET api.example.com/users route. See documentation on routing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanks to the hint of Yuli

```
[Route ("[controller]")]
public class UsersController {

    // GET api.example.com/users
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers () {
        ...
          var users = await _db.Users.GetAll();
          return Ok (users);
    }

    // GET api.example.com/{tenant}/users
    [HttpGet("/{tenant}/[controller]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers (Guid tenant) {
        ...
          var users = await _db.Users.GetAllByTentant(tenant);
          return Ok (users);
    }
}
```